# Negative Int XOR with Hexidecimal Integer Constant and Decimal Integer will produce Different Results?

Tags: sql-server, int, hex, decimal, xor

I tried to create a table 'MyTable' and add a field "field1" with small int type.

Then I add a negative number -12289 to the field1.

Then I execute the following SQL query:

```
select field1 ^ 0xcfff from MyTable
```

The result is zero.

But if I replace the hexidecimal integer constant with the decimal integer constant, as below:

```
select field1 ^ 53247 from MyTable
```

The result is -65536.

Why?

The only clue is on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> Integer constants greater than 2,147,483,647 are converted to the decimal data type, not the bigint data type.

But both 0xcfff and 53247 is much more smaller than 2,147,483,647. Why do they will produce difference results?

**Update:**

To my understanding, the keypoint of this question is that we can cast 0xcfff to small int, like this:

```
select cast(0xcfff as smallint)
```

But we CANNOT cast 53247 to small int, the following line will cause overflow:

```
select cast(53247 as smallint)
```

This is different from C/C++. In C/C++, both casts are OK.

Comment: You're dealing with different data types and seeing issues due to type conversions. `0xcfff` isn't a hexadecimal constant - it's a `binary(2)` value. The `smallint` data type has a range of -32768 to 32767, so when `0xcfff` is cast to `smallint` its decimal equivalent is `-12289`... and `-12289 ^ -12289 = 0`. The value `53247` is outside the `smallint` range so is converted to at least an `int`, which causes `field1` to get converted to `int` as well for the xor operation. With both `field1` and `53247` converted to int the xor result is `-65536`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, why 0xcfff as binary(2) will be casted to smallint(-12289), not int, while 53247 will be casted to int, not smallint(-12289) when the other operator is smallint?

Comment: Because `smallint` is a signed 16-bit value and `0xcfff` is two bytes (16-bits). `53247` cannot be represented as a signed 16-bit value so gets cast to a signed 32-bit int.

Comment: SQL Server does not have unsigned data types - perhaps that is the clue you were missing?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I know SQL Server does not have unsigned data types, but originally think it support to cast 53247 to smallint, like C++ do. But that is not true. See my "Update" of the post.

Comment: You cannot "successfully" cast 53247 to a short (signed int16) in C++ - the stored value is -12289.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little known bit you are missing here is [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). Here is how you can check it:

```sql
declare @t table (
    Id smallint not null
);

insert into @t (Id)
select -12289;

select sq.*,
    sql_variant_property(sq.XBin, 'BaseType') as [BinType],
    sql_variant_property(sq.XDec, 'BaseType') as [DecType]
from (
    select t.Id,
        t.Id ^ 0xcfff as [XBin],
        t.Id ^ 53247 as [XDec]
    from @t t
) sq;
```

The binary literal `0xcfff` takes 2 bytes, so it can be implicitly cast to the `smallint` type, which the column itself has. The decimal literal, however, is interpreted as `int` (not because it requires more than 2 bytes, but because SQL Server [always interprets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql#integer-constants) integer literals under 2^32-1 as having this data type, and everything greater [interpreted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql#converting-integer-data) as `decimal`). This means that now the column has to be implicitly converted to `int` which has higher precedence than `smallint`, and its sign is preserved during conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This because of the length of your data.
You should use the same byte length when you execute bitwise operators:

```
1100 1111 1111 1111 <--  -12289 as smallint (word)
1100 1111 1111 1111 <--  CFFF (-12289) (word)
0000 0000 0000 0000 <--  XOR result = 0 (word)

1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 1111 1111 1111 <--  -12289 as int (double word)
0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1111 1111 1111 <--  53247 (0000CFFF) (double word)
1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 <--  XOR result = -65536 (double word)
```

You can try to change length:

```
select cast(-12289 as int) ^ 0x00cfff, -12289 ^ cast(0x00cfff as int)
```